# Use a for loop to print a dictionary

Tags: python

I need to use for loop specifically to print a dictionary. Here is what I have:

```
# To create lists
products= ['Hammers', 'Shovels', 'Picks', 'Buckets', 'Rope']
prices= ['$11.50', '$25.00', '$13.45', '$2.95', '$9.99']
#To create dictionary
products_prices= dict(zip(products, prices))
for products in prices:
 print(products_prices)
```

This is my result:

```
{'Hammers': '$11.50', 'Shovels': '$25.00', 'Picks': '$13.45', 'Buckets': '$2.95', 'Rope'$9.99'}{'Hammers': '$11.50', 'Shovels': '$25.00', 'Picks': '$13.45', 'Buckets': '$2.95', 'Rope': '$9.99'}
{'Hammers': '$11.50', 'Shovels': '$25.00', 'Picks': '$13.45', 'Buckets': '$2.95', 'Rope': '$9.99'}
{'Hammers': '$11.50', 'Shovels': '$25.00', 'Picks': '$13.45', 'Buckets': '$2.95', 'Rope': '$9.99'}
{'Hammers': '$11.50', 'Shovels': '$25.00', 'Picks': '$13.45', 'Buckets': '$2.95', 'Rope': '$9.99'}
```

This is what I am wanting:

```
Hammers: $11.50
Shovels: 25.00
etc...
```

Comment: Try: `for key, value in prices.items()` then `print(key, value)`. Currently, you are iterating the dict values, and printing the *entire* dict on each iteration.

Comment: Why do you need a loop at all?  Can't you just print the entire dictionary in one go, with a single `print(products_prices)`?

Comment: Do you care about removing the single quotes from around the values?

Comment: No, I do not care about the quotes. And I wish I did not have to loop it but that is a specific requirement from my professor

Comment: The reason you get duplicate output is because the loop runs once for each item in the dictionary -- but inside the loop, you're printing _the whole dictionary_, not just the current item.  So, since the dict has five items, the whole dict is printed five times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dict.items()` method, which returns a `dict_items` object, which you can then iterate over, as in the following code:

```
for key, value in products_prices.items():
  print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

Output:

```
Hammers: $11.50
Shovels: $25.00
Picks: $13.45
Buckets: $2.95
Rope: $9.99
```

This also uses a f-string, or format-string, to make printing the values more concise.

The issue with your code is that in your inner loop, you're printing the entire `product_prices` dictionary instead of the relevant elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# To create lists
products= ['Hammers', 'Shovels', 'Picks', 'Buckets', 'Rope']
prices= ['$11.50', '$25.00', '$13.45', '$2.95', '$9.99']
# To create dictionary
products_prices = dict(zip(products, prices))
# To iterate over the dictionary keys
for products in products_prices:
    print(products)
# To iterate over the dictionary values
for prices in products_prices.values():
    print(prices)
```

Answer (score -1):

Replacing:

```
for products in prices:
 print(products_prices).
```

with:

```
for key,value in products_prices.items():
    print(key, value)
```

will give you an output of:

```
Hammers $11.50
Shovels $25.00
Picks $13.45
Buckets $2.95
Rope $9.99
```

Comment: This code will not correctly output the `: `.